# Hereditary C*-subalgebras of the unitization of a hereditary C*-subalgebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $A$ be a unital C*-algebra with unit $1$, and $B$ a non-unital hereditary C*-subalgebra of $A$. Suppose $J$  is a proper hereditary C*-subalgebra of $B\oplus C1$ (the unitization of B). Is $J$ also a hereditary C*-subalgebra of $A$?

Answer (score 0):

No. As a simple example, take $A = C([0,1])$, $B = C_0([0,1))$ and $J = C_0((0,1])$.